# Partition table by date rand oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When creating below table I'm getting error missing left parenthesis, kindly sugget -

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_WRK_KYC_RPT_FINAL AS
SELECT /*+PARALLEL(20)*/ * FROM PROD.WRK_KYC_RPT_FINAL
PARTITION BY RANGE (T_DATE_DESC)
INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'MONTH')) 
    (PARTITION TRANSACTION_01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-FEB-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')))
    (PARTITION TRANSACTION_02 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-MAR-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')))
    (PARTITION TRANSACTION_03 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')))
    (PARTITION TRANSACTION_04 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-MAY-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')))
    (PARTITION TRANSACTION_05 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUN-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')))
    (PARTITION TRANSACTION_05 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')));
```

When creating below table I'm getting error missing left parenthesis

Comment: put the select ... after the partition clause

Comment: You have TRANSACTION_05 twice...

Answer (score 2):

You have your `SELECT` portion too early. You must provide all your `CREATE TABLE` clauses first, before the `AS SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_WRK_KYC_RPT_FINAL 
PARALLEL (DEGREE 16)
PARTITION BY RANGE (T_DATE_DESC)
INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'MONTH')) 
  (PARTITION TRANSACTION_01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-FEB-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')))
AS
SELECT * FROM PROD.WRK_KYC_RPT_FINAL
```

Other notes:

1. Since you are setting up interval partitioning, you should only provide one (your first) explicit partition. For range partitioning at least one partition must be specified at create time, but the interval will automatically create any others needed when the data loads.
2. A list of explicit partitions is wrapped in parentheses, but individual partitions in that list are separated by commas, not parentheses. But again, you only need one because of the interval.
3. Lastly, it's better in a CTAS to ask for parallelism in the `CREATE TABLE` section rather than using a hint in the `SELECT`. That way it parallelizes the data loading itself. Otherwise, it would bottleneck on the serialized data load and the select parallelism would be of no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have never create table as select with partitions. First create the partitioned table, then insert select into it.
And the create table should be along the following lines:

```
create table zzz_t (
val_dt date not null,
ctr_nmbr varchar2(200) not null
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (val_dt) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'MONTH')) (
  PARTITION TRANSACTION_01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-FEB-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')), 
  PARTITION TRANSACTION_02 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-MAR-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')), 
  PARTITION TRANSACTION_03 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')), 
  PARTITION TRANSACTION_04 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-MAY-2023','DD-MON-YYYY')),
  PARTITION TRANSACTION_05 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUN-2023','DD-MON-YYYY'))
) 
    ;
```

Couldn't guess the columns in the table you are selecting from, but it should be quite easy for you to extract the DDL of that table and copy and paste.